# Как обратиться к дню недели(вс) в air datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Т.е. как мне записать ее в переменную. Чтобы после как-то оперировать с этой датой?
Но не получается разобраться :(
Документация - http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/index-ru.html

*Прим:*

Есть 2 input-a. 1 - air-datepicker, 2 - результат выполнения. И есть условие - если выбран 7 день (вс) любой недели и любого месяца в календаре, то вывести, допустим, график работы 10:00 - 15:00, иначе же 10:00 - 20:00 (пн-сб)

Comment: Покажите ваш код и постарайтесь объяснить что не получается.... А так у вас идёт инпут, получайте просто его [значение](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: Кода нет. Но попытаюсь максимально подробно объяснить чего хочу добиться. Есть 2 input-a. 1 - air-datepicker, 2 - результат выполнения.  И есть условие - если выбран 7 день (вс) любой недели и любого месяца в календаре, то вывести, допустим, график работы 10:00 - 15:00, иначе же 10:00 - 20:00 (пн-сб).

Вопрос - как обратиться к 7 дню недели любой недели.

Comment: Там в инструкции есть раздел Actions with time. Читайте внимательней мануалы. на SO готовых решений не предоставляют, выкладываете свой код, говорите что не так и вам помогают разобраться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='timepicker-actions-exmpl' />
<script>
  var start = new Date()
  $('#timepicker-actions-exmpl').datepicker({

    onSelect: function(fd, d, picker) {
      if (!d) return;

      var day = d.getDay();

      if (day == 0) {
        console.log("Воскр")
      } else {
        console.log("нет")
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

Пример под ваш вопрос.